# Can't pass XML to XSLT (no results show)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to pass this XML above to XSLT. I want to show the results on a table. I think I'm doing everything right but when I test nothing appears!
Can someone help to see what I doing wrong?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<search>

  <searchWord>gta</searchWord>

  <resultsList>

    <resultsFromLeft>
      <link>link from left</link>
      <titulo>title from left</titulo>
      <descricao>description from left</description>
    </resultsFromLeft>

    <resultsFromRight>
      <link>link from right</link>
      <title>Title from right</title>
      <description>description from right</description>
    </resultsFromRight>

  </resultsList>

  <totalresults>
    10000
  </totalresults>

</search>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Search Gta</h2>

        <table border="1">

          <th>Search Word</th>
          <th>Results from left link</th>
          <th>Results from left description</th>
          <th>Results from left title</th>
          <th>Results from right link</th>
          <th>Results from right description</th>
          <th>Results from right title</th>
          <th>Total Results</th>

          <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </tr>

        </table>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="resultsList">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="resultsFromLeft/link"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="resultsFromLeft/title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="resultsFromLeft/description"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="resultsFromRight/link"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="resultsFromRight/title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="resultsFromRight/description"/></td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT engine are you using? How do you invoke the XSLT engine? How do you "pass" the XML to the engine?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!Im testing for now in he w3schools site, here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the "description" tags isn't started properly in input xml. And there is no declaration for xsl namespace and version in stylesheet element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

Comment: Thank you...i didnt know that the namespace was required! It worked!

Comment: Please don't edit your question after it has been answered, particularly if the edit makes nonsense of the answer. Other people will read this thread in the future, and it doesn't make any sense if the errors in the supplied XSLT have been corrected.